# Power supply problems

Tags: boot, laptop, power-supply, power

I recently had a laptop that would not boot a range of things.

It would not boot the existing installation of windows for the SSD.

It would not boot Ubuntu from a USB.

It would not boot the OEM bootable restore software from the recovery drive.

Every time I tried to boot any of these the spinning logo froze during boot up.

EasyUs backup and the windows installation media did work however when I tried to install windows it crashed during the install process in the same manner.

I tried many things to fix this and nothing worked.

Anyway it has unexpectedly started working again.

The only things I did between the last failed start-up and the laptop working again was to attempt to remove the laptop cover unsuccessfully and unplug the power supply ( so it ran on the battery )

Could a faulty external power supply have been causing this issue?

If yes it is currently working with the power supply plugged in but the power supply has itself been unplugged from the power socket for a few hours ( previously it has always been on without interruption even if it was not plugged into the laptop ) could this result in a faulty power supply temporally working ( maybe overheating issues were the cause )

Comment: Glad you got it working again. Though it's unlikely that the power supply caused the issue, a better test would be to *substitute* another power supply. A capacitor going bad could put a lot of noise on the DC output -- whether that would produce the issue you saw is another question.

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional details. Like what exact model of laptop? What OS does it normally run on? Did you purchase it as new or used? Did the problems suddenly come up or did they gradually appear over time?

Comment: What is “ORM bootable restore software”?

Comment: "What is “ORM bootable restore software”?"

ORM = original equipment manufacturer ( a typo of OEM ), in this case dell

Its the system restore/recovery solution which comes with it, in this case a bootable package on a separate partition.

Comment: windows 11, purchased new in 2019/2018

Comment: Static electricity accumulation can cause such problems, and you might have drained it as a side-effect of your unsuccessful hardware manipulations, so "fixed" it.